# Creating a ListView/TreeView using Category (Control Panel-Like) View

Tags: .net, listview, treeview, managed, categories

I currently have an application which uses a regular ListView with groups to show a bunch of modules.

I would like to use a Category view. Category view is the new view introduced in Windows Vista for the Control Panel:

[image: Windows 7 Control Panel]

Is there a third party control or a way (via API) to create a ListView which mimics the behavior of the Windows 7 Control Panel?

- Categories with icons and action links.
- Separate events for Category Click and Action Click.
- One or two column layout
- Separators between action links or lines

**EDIT:** Seems like Windows is using a TreeView (SysTreeView32) control internally for this.

Comment: Please read: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20590/room-for-nulluserexception-and-andrew-moore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a ListView, not a TreeView, its the enigmatic DirectUIHWnd.  Been around a long time, back to XP's Welcome screen.  Still not documented.

Comment: So basically I'm stuck creating a UserControl to replicate this behavior? Spy++ shows a SysTreeView32 beneath that DirectUIHwnd.